# Confused of three deverbal nouns in dictionary

Tags: grammar, verbs, descriptive-grammar, style-manuals, deverbal-nouns

I have learnt something about deverbal nouns before.

> a)These readings are quite interesting  (Here it means books,refers to something)
>
> b)I did some reading of history books(Here it means the act, it has verbal characteristics)

But some words in dictionary are quite confusing, please help check the following sentences:

> Dealing: business activities, the relations that you have with somebody in business;
> eg: I knew nothing of his business dealings (Here the meaning of "dealing" should be the same with a)? refers to something?)
>
> Greeting: something thay you say or do to greet people(here should be the same with a)?
>
> Swimming: an activity or sport(Here should be the same as b)? Because it has some verbal characterisitcs)

Please help me to check my thought.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund

Comment: _I did some reading_ does not use a deverbal noun. As you say, some verbal characteristics are retained, though 'reading' is closer to the nounal end of the cline here. A reasonable test for a deverbal noun usage is whether a plural variant is available. His paintings are expensive [yes]. His painting the wall is annoying me [no]. Painting is fun [no]. I didn't want _him_ painting the wall [no]. He is painting the wall [no]. An analysis of ing-forms using the gradience model is given in ACGEL by Quirk et al; if you look up 'Quirk gradience' here you should find it mentioned.

Comment: Yes normally the 's' works but there are some exceptions like:killing (it is act but we can say killings)

Comment: 'Deverbal nouns' are defined according to their grammatical behaviour rather than how closely related to 'verbal notion' they are. Even with five paintings, someone painted them. I agree, though, that this is an inadequate model: 'killings' is a deverbal noun, but 'paintings' seems far less 'verby'.

Comment: So painting（you mean pictures） is a noun swimming reading shouting  killing these are about act right？